# How to integrate Django with Kafka using Python?

Tags: python, django, apache-kafka

I want to pass input from **Django to Kafka**.
I have fields *a,b,c,d* and *h1,h2* and *h3*. All fields are **input from the user**.
I want to start my Kafka process as soon as the user enters submit button on my Django front-end interface.
All fields are being saved in **Mysql**.

I can only find possible solutions in Java using Mysql connectors.

Is there any method or connector with which i can pass my **input from user on Django interface to kafka using python** ?

**a,b,c,d** - Access Tokens

**h1,h2,h3** - Search queries(keywords)

Answer (score 13):

First install `kafka-python`, then import following statements in `views.py`.

1. `from kafka import KafkaProducer`
2. `from kafka import KafkaConsumer`
3. `from json import loads`
4. `import json`
5. `import pickle //pickle converts data into byte array`

Then write `Producer` view as following.

This code converts data into a byte array and send to kafka. Instead of sending json message v you can send your data like v=your data.

```
def kfk(request):   
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='127.0.0.1:9092')
    v = {
        'msg': {
            'hello': 'world',
        },
    }
    serialized_data = pickle.dumps(v, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    producer.send('Ptopic', serialized_data)
    return HttpResponse(200)
```

To consume data:

```
def cons(request):
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('Ptopic', 
        bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], 
        api_version=(0, 10) 
        #,consumer_timeout_ms=1000
    )

    for message in consumer:
        deserialized_data = pickle.loads(message.value) 
        print(deserialized_data)
```

Note: Kafka consumer view should always in running mode then try to produce here Ptopic is my topic name.

Comment: Should there be two instances of Django, One Producer, Two consumers, and the consumer code should go in the Consumer instance?

Comment: yes, we can have multiple consumers for single producer

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just use the KafkaProducer from the kafka-python package and you will be set.

`pip install kafka-python`

Then in your Django function:

```
def myfunc(request):
  from kafka import KafkaProducer
  producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='kafkaBroker:9092')
  producer.send('foobar', b'test')
  return HttpResponse(200)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `confluent-kafka` package for connecting from Python to kafka.

To do this in a standard way, I have created a wrapper over the KafkaProducer class of the confluent library and created a singleton class of that wrapper. It will take care of initiation procedures whenever it is called for the first time.

Below is the code.

```
import json
import uuid

from confluent_kafka import Producer
from django.conf import settings


class KafkaProducerService:
    __instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if KafkaProducerService.__instance is not None:
            raise Exception(f"{__name__} - This class is a singleton!")

        kafka_config = settings.SOURCE_POLLER_KAFKA_CONFIG["kafka"]
        self.producer = Producer(kafka_config)

        KafkaProducerService.__instance = self

    @staticmethod
    def value_serializer(message: dict):
        return json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8')

    def send_message(self, topic, message, key=None):
        if not key:
            key = str(uuid.uuid4())

        return self.producer.produce(topic, KafkaProducerService.value_serializer(message), key)

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance(reinit=False):
        """ Static access method. """

        if reinit:
            KafkaProducerService.__instance = None

        if KafkaProducerService.__instance is None:
            KafkaProducerService()

        return KafkaProducerService.__instance
```

From the View class or service class that services the view class, you can just call the `KafkaProducerService.getInstance().send(topic, message, key)`. The settings file will have all the connection-related configs like bootstrap.servers, etc.

The message is assumed to be a dict and the key as a string. you can just tweak it for your use case in the serializer of the `KafaProducerService` class if you want.

To know more about the standard way of integration for both Kafka producer and consumer, check on this blog -

https://medium.com/@vignesh865/kafka-with-python-django-9bb9aeb379ac